Spark cache inside a function
I have this toy example function returning a cached spark DataFrame (DF):
def foo(df):
    try:
        base = complicated_query(df)
        base.cache()                                    # lazy cache
        base.count()                                    # trigger cache - wrong design???
        num1 = base.withColumn('number', f.lit('1'))
        num2 = base.withColumn('number', f.lit('2'))
        return num1.union(num2)
    finally:
        None
        # base.unpersist()

The purpose of foo is to simply encapsulate temporary variables (DataFrames) which I don't want to have in the outer scope. base is some complicated DF used twice, hence I cache it. My questions are around the explicit count call (suggested by ChatGPT). This is to trigger caching but I feel like it is a wrong design.

Why do we need count (an action) at this point? What is the gain? The actual caching would happen anyway on the first action to the return value of foo if I didn't call count.
I noticed that calling foo twice with the same input df has different execution times: first is slow, which is expected since a count is called. But the second is almost instant. Why is that? Surely base is already cached and then count is trivial, but the base reference in the second run is a different reference than that in the first run. How does spark know that it can reuse a cached DF from the first run? (whose memory btw I leaked I guess since after foo exits I cannot unpersist it.)
Do we really have memory leak when foo exits? How can I unpersist base? Do I have to unpersist at all? I know there is spark.catalog.clearCache() to wipe out all cached DFs but I would like to do this explicitly for base. That's why there is/was a finally clause in the function, to prevent a leak, but that was a failed attempt as in that case I was freeing up the cache before I could even use it...

Can you please help resolve these?

Count is called to cache the df which helps in optimizing further operations

.explain(True) can tell you a lot for your second question.

does below answer helped you? @Andras Vanyolos


The caching happens lazily and only when the action is performed the dataframe is cached.
Here, the count() is used because to benefit  subsequent operations from cached base

num1 = base.withColumn('number', f.lit('1'))
num2 = base.withColumn('number', f.lit('2'))

Above, operations look for the cached base and use that dataframe to reduce latency.

When foo executed for the first time the caching is done, and it takes some time but when it executed second time with different object it checks the logical plan. Possible reason is when the logical plan matches it uses the same cached results.

Here, are the results i got.
2 different Dataframe object
print(id(df1))
print(id(df2))

Output:
140492486613904 
140492486794896

Execution time


import time

start_time = time.time()
d_foo = foo(df1)
end_time = time.time()

elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
print(f"Time taken df1: {elapsed_time:.6f} seconds")


start_time = time.time()
t_foo = foo(df2)
end_time = time.time()

elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
print(f"Time taken df2: {elapsed_time:.6f} seconds")


Output
Time taken df1: 1.444211 seconds
Time taken df2: 0.730322 seconds

Here, second executed much faster.
Logical plan comparison.
logical_plan_df1 = d_foo._jdf.queryExecution().logical()
logical_plan_df2 = t_foo._jdf.queryExecution().logical()

are_logical_plans_equal = logical_plan_df1.canEqual(logical_plan_df2)
print(f"\nAre the logical plans identical? {are_logical_plans_equal}")

Output:
Are the logical plans identical? True

Here, the plans are same, so it takes the cached results.
Also, every call you make to foo the dataframe is cached and spark holds it in memory. So you need to unpersist them.
Here, is the below code.
def foo(df):
    try:
        base = df
        base.cache()                                    
        base.count()                                    
        num1 = base.withColumn('number', lit('1'))
        num2 = base.withColumn('number', lit('2'))
        num1.explain()
        return num1.union(num2)
    finally:
        if base is not None:
            base.unpersist()
            num1.explain()

Here, you can check the plan using explain(),  if it consists of InMemoryTableScan then it is using cached dataframe, after unpersist it should use the existing dataframe.
